# In Rust, how do I create a HashSet from the keys of a HashMap?

Tags: rust

I have two `HashMap`s and want to compute the intersection of the keys. Is it possible to construct a `HashSet` out of whatever `HashMap::keys()` returns? For example:

```rust
use std::collections::{HashSet, HashMap};

fn main() {
    let mut map1: HashMap<i64, i64> = HashMap::new();
    let mut map2: HashMap<i64, i64> = HashMap::new();

    // Add some values into the HashMaps for demonstration
    map1.insert(1, 10);
    map1.insert(5, 50);
    map2.insert(3, 30);
    map2.insert(5, 50);

    let set1: HashSet<i64> = HashSet::from(map1.keys());  // How to do this?
    let set2: HashSet<i64> = HashSet::from(map2.keys());  // How to do this?

    let set3 = set1.intersection(&set2); // What I'm looking to accomplish
    // set3 should contain [5], as this is the one key shared by the two HashMaps
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for an efficient solution, or for a simple solution?

Comment: I'm trying to learn more about the language, so I'd love both an elegant but maybe slow solution and an example of a fast solution.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### The simple solution

Your code only needs a few tweaks to actually compile ([see Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c28515af943ccd2a084d634bf4e48dd5)):

```
use std::collections::{HashSet, HashMap};

fn main() {
    let mut map1 = HashMap::new();
    let mut map2 = HashMap::new();

    // Add some values into the HashMaps for demonstration
    map1.insert(1, 10);
    map1.insert(5, 50);
    map2.insert(3, 30);
    map2.insert(5, 50);

    let set1: HashSet<i64> = map1.keys().cloned().collect();
    let set2: HashSet<i64> = map2.keys().cloned().collect();

    let set3 = set1.intersection(&set2);
    println!("{:?}", set3);
}
```

In particular, note `map1.keys().cloned().collect()`:

- `HashMap<K, V>::keys()` returns an `Iterator<Item = &'a K>`,
- `.cloned()` transforms that to an `Iterator<Item = K>`,
- `.collect()` builds a collection from that, since `HashSet` implements the `FromIterator` trait.

However, this is not very efficient:

- Complexity wise: `O(map1.size() + map2.size())`.
- Memory wise: potentially large allocations.

#### The efficient solution

Implement `intersection` directly on the keys of `HashMap`.

Comment: _"lots of allocations"_ - only two extra allocations. `HashMap::keys()` returns an `ExactSizeIterator`, so the collector can allocate the `HashSet` in one step.

Comment: @PeterHall: Rephrased, it's not the number the problem, it's the size of them.

Comment: What does `&'a K` stand for? Some sort of reference to an item of type `K`?

Comment: @MarijnvanVliet: Yes, an immutable reference to a key of the hash map.

Answer (score 7):

You just need to collect into the `HashSet`:

```
let set1: HashSet<i64> = map1.keys().copied().collect(); 
let set2: HashSet<i64> = map2.keys().copied().collect();
```

Using `copied()` will dereference the keys and copy them, since you want a `HashSet<i64>` not a `HashSet<&i64>`