# Idiomatically dereference map keys

Tags: rust

I'd like to get two `HashSet`s out of the keys of two `HashMap`s in Rust. My code looks like the following:

```
let mut wire1_map: HashMap<(i32, i32), u32> = HashMap::new();
get_route(&mut wire1_map, &wire1);
let mut wire2_map: HashMap<(i32, i32), u32> = HashMap::new();
get_route(&mut wire2_map, &wire2);

let wire1_set: HashSet<(i32, i32)> = wire1_map.keys().map(|x| *x).collect();
let wire2_set: HashSet<(i32, i32)> = wire2_map.keys().map(|x| *x).collect();

let is = wire1_set.intersection(&wire2_set);
let m_dist = is.map(|ele| calc_distance((0, 0), *ele)).min().unwrap();
```

I want to get `HashSet`s to use `intersection()`.

The code runs, but my questions are:

- In general, is this idiomatic Rust code?
- Is there an easier (more idiomatic) way to dereference each key of a map?

Comment: It would be more idiomatic to use `.copied()` instead of `.map(|x| *x)`, unless you are using a slightly old version of Rust, which doesn't have the method.

Comment: See this **VERY SIMILAR** question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59156305/in-rust-how-do-i-create-a-hashset-from-the-keys-of-a-hashmap